# LaTeX (TikZ) image centering

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem with the horizontal alignment of an image. I have compiled the image from the [`matlab` extension](http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/) and added it to my LaTeX file with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth 
\setlength\figureheight{6cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{9cm}
\input{img/ConvPlot.tikz}
\caption{Convergentieplot bij $\nu=-0.7$ en $M_{ref}=M(Q=30)$.}
\label{ConvPlot}
\end{figure}
```

LaTeX automatically centers the image width **and** the vertical axis width. But I want only the figure box centered, not the image and axis. Is there any way to achieve this?

Image:

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/35iwxs4.jpg]

Comment: You can try `trim left={<x coordinate or point>}` or change the bounding box according to section 4.18.6 Bounding Box Restrictions of the pgfplots manual.

Comment: If the plot is generated using PGFPlots, you can also use `trim axis left` in the `tikzpicture` options to automatically trim at the axis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why your figure is not centered the way you wanted is because the bounding box of the figure includes the labels of the vertical axis. There are two ways to tell TikZ to ignore the width added by the vertical axis labels.

**Method 1.** Add

```
\pgfplotsset{
  ylabel style={overlay},
  yticklabel style={overlay},
}
```

in your `.tex` document (where you add it doesn't seem to matter, as long as it's before the current figure) This may produce a global effect (unless the `\pgfplotsset` is issued within a `figure` environment). That is, *all* the bounding boxes of your subsequent PGF plots will be "trimmed".

**Method 2.** Open your `ConvPlot.tikz` file with a text editor, find `ylabel={...},`, and add

```
ylabel style={overlay},
yticklabel style={overlay},
```

below it. This will have a local effect. That is, only the bounding box of this particular figure will be changed. All other PGF plots will still have the default bounding boxes (that includes the labels of the vertical axis).

The following two images contrasts the effects with and without modifying the `ylabel`/`yticklabel` styles, respectively.

[image: ylabel style modified] [image: ylabel style not modified]

Comment: If the `\pgfplotsset` command is issued in the body of a `figure` environment it will cease to have effect at the end of it.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for noticing that. The answer has been modified accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I try to give a more general answer to cover some other situations

**Part A)  Centering only a part of a latex image**

Here a picture [image]

I want to center only the window without the background. It's possible manually. The idea is simple first I used `\includegraphics[trim= 98 0 0 13,clip]` 98 an 13 are determined manually. Then When you get what you want you can write `\includegraphics[trim= 98 0 0 13]{tm.png}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[]{tm.png}
\caption{tm}
\label{ConvPlot}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[trim= 98 0 0 13]{tm.png}
\caption{tm}
\label{ConvPlot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Part B) Centering only a part of a latex tikz image (without pgfplots)**

The problem can appear with a simple tikz picture. In this can you need to use the tikz option `trim left` with a dimensions or with an anchor (I think it's possible ...)

Here a little file :  fig.tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left= -1.5cm]
\node[rectangle,draw,minimum width=1 cm, minimum height=2 cm, fill=cyan!20] (a) {}
node[rectangle,draw=red,fill=orange!20,minimum width=2 cm, minimum height=1 cm] (b) [left= 0pt of a] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You can write in your main file

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{fig.tikz}
\caption{tikz}
\label{tikz}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

But if you can't modify this file and if the first line is

```
  \begin{tikzpicture} without [trim left= -1.5cm]``
```

You can write in the main file before the figure :

```
 \tikzset{every picture/.style={trim left=-1.5cm}}
```

Perhaps it's possible to use an anchor like this

\tikzset{every picture/.style={trim left=(a.left)}}

[image]

**Part C) Centering only a part of a latex pgfplots image**

Interesting if the picture contains only **one** pgfplots graphic and **nothing else**

You can try an idea from Jake, the trick is `trim axis left,trim axis right`but it's possible to use the tools used in part B.

Here a little file pgfplot.tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[width=5cm,ylabel=looong label,ylabel style={rotate=-90}]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And in the main file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}

%\tikzset{every picture/.style={trim axis left,trim axis right}}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{pgfplot.tikz}
\caption{pgfplot}
\label{pgfplot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you can't modify the file pgfplot.tikz (it's not your file ...) you can try

```
  \tikzset{every picture/.style={trim axis left,trim axis right}}
```

and you get

[image]