# Pgfplot figure off-center because of axis label

Tags: pgfplots

My figures are always off-center because the right axis is trimmed closer to the figure than the left. Do I have to manually extend the right axis by an adhoc amount every time?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}




\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        %width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
        %height = 8cm,
        %major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar,%=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=20pt,
        %ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {Deposition \%},
        symbolic x coords={{4  ac.h$^{-1}$},{6  ac.h$^{-1}$}},
        xtick = {{4  ac.h$^{-1}$},{6  ac.h$^{-1}$}},
        ymax=80,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
    ]


        \addplot [fill=black, draw=black,bar shift=3pt] coordinates {({4  ac.h$^{-1}$},61.66779959)}; %\addlegendentry{4  ac.h$^{-1}$}
\addplot [fill=white, draw=black,bar shift=-3pt] coordinates {({6  ac.h$^{-1}$},65.77432124)};
%\addplot [fill=white, draw=black, bar shift=0.5ex] table [x=X, y=6ACH]  {\datatable}; \addlegendentry{6  ac.h$^{-1}$}


    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't seem to work for standalone document class [pgfplots and figure centering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25417/pgfplots-and-figure-centering)

and this is adhoc: [Centering a TikZ picture around an area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/centering-a-tikz-picture-around-an-area)
Excel: 5 seconds but no Tex formatting and wrong fonts.
[image]

**EDIT**

Axis labels are cut off and part of the ytick
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.0416666666666667,0,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]


\begin{axis}[%
width=6.17578125in,
height=2.23276041666667in,
area legend,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=5.5,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
xticklabels={Equipment,Patient,{Hygiene products},Near-bed,Far-bed},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.35,
ytick={  0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4},
ylabel={Probability density},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
legend style={at={(0.143572984749455,0.733206590621038)},anchor=south west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot[ybar,bar width=0.282321428571429in,bar shift=-0.176450892857143in,fill=mycolor1,draw=black] plot coordinates{(1,0.163793103)
(2,0.164367816)
(3,0.141954023)
(4,0.279310345)
(5,0.250574713)};

\addlegendentry{Smith et al.};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.5 0\\
5.5 0\\
};
\addplot[ybar,bar width=0.282321428571429in,bar shift=0.176450892857143in,fill=white,draw=black] plot coordinates{(1,0.165289256)
(2,0.185950413)
(3,0.157024793)
(4,0.285123967)
(5,0.20661157)};

\addlegendentry{Adjusted YAB};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Producing nonsense in 5 seconds is not better than making a decent plot with others :) So make a fair comparison. Don't underestimate the force... Don't forget to floss. :P http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109299/latex-tikz-image-centering

Comment: If you use `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]`, the axis will be centered correctly.

Comment: @Jake That's what I thought. But it cuts off my ylabel

Comment: @HCAI: Kind of, yes: It's no longer inside the bounding box, but it's still in the pdf. If you include the file in a document, the label will show up correctly.

Comment: @percusse Undoubtedly accurate on all accounts. So: `Producing nonsense in 5 seconds is not better than making a decent plot in hours :)`

Comment: @HCAI For me it's the other way around. With that new menus in Office it takes hours to make a decent task even though I consider Excel to be the only MS product that is good. So it goes both ways. You'll get faster if you keep on using it.

Comment: @percusse touché! Although I do think the definition of `decent` is what's really the issue here. In many ways most things that Excel produces are "fine" as standalone objects but the lack of a latex interpreter for the labels is really a sore point. Don't MS think people need mathematical notation? Or am I in a world of my own?

Comment: PS. you'll have to admit that my cac-handed attempt with pgfplots has not done that plot justice. In fact at first glance they tell two different stories, the former saying no difference. the latter quite a bit.

Comment: @Jake The labels and now axis numbers are often missing when I import using `\includegraphics{some_guff.pdf}`. Are you suggesting it only looks ok when printed or is there something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: @HCAI: They shouldn't be missing, they just shouldn't be inside the bounding box of the image. Could you edit your question to include an example of when this happens?

Comment: @Jake That's what I thought too (as you explained that earlier). It appears that altering the border size: `\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}` makes the axis labels appear or disappear in the final document.

Answer (score 13):

If you use `\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]`, the axis will be centered correctly.

Answer (score 3):

What I came up with is to simply add a node with the size of the bounding box, with an `inner xsep`, while using the axis as a bounding box and `overlay` for `ylabel` and `yticklabel`:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        use as bounding box,
        ylabel style={overlay},
        yticklabel style={overlay},
        % ...
    ]
        % ...
    \end{axis}

    \node[
        draw=none,
        fit=(current bounding box.north west)
            (current bounding box.south east),
        inner xsep=5em % adjust as needed
    ] at (current bounding box.center) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

With the example of this question, this is the result:

[image: pgfplot center]

This did also work when including it as a standalone in another TeX file.