# Pgfplot figure off-center

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I create a tikzpicture in standalone mode (see code below). Then import the resultant .pdf file into my document via `\includegraphics` (see pic). However the axis labels are cut off and part of the ytick when using `[trim axis left, trim axis right]`. If I don't use that command it looks fine but is not centered any more. Any thoughts?

PS this is a duplicate but perhaps more concise of this [Pgfplot figure off-center because of axis label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109598/pgfplot-figure-off-center-because-of-axis-label)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.0416666666666667,0,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]


\begin{axis}[%
width=6.17578125in,
height=2.23276041666667in,
area legend,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=5.5,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5},
xticklabels={Equipment,Patient,{Hygiene products},Near-bed,Far-bed},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.35,
ytick={  0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4},
ylabel={Probability density},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
legend style={at={(0.143572984749455,0.733206590621038)},anchor=south west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot[ybar,bar width=0.282321428571429in,bar shift=-0.176450892857143in,fill=mycolor1,draw=black] plot coordinates{(1,0.163793103)
(2,0.164367816)
(3,0.141954023)
(4,0.279310345)
(5,0.250574713)};

\addlegendentry{Smith et al.};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0.5 0\\
5.5 0\\
};
\addplot[ybar,bar width=0.282321428571429in,bar shift=0.176450892857143in,fill=white,draw=black] plot coordinates{(1,0.165289256)
(2,0.185950413)
(3,0.157024793)
(4,0.285123967)
(5,0.20661157)};

\addlegendentry{Adjusted YAB};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is (manually) increase the border around the graph. The `standalone` package allows the left and right borders to be set independently of the top and bottom borders. So, if you change

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
```

to

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={38pt 12pt}]{standalone}
```

then your y-axis labels will not be cropped, and your graph will remain centred. The only downside is that this is a bit of a dirty hack!

Comment: Very nice! thank you. By the way how did you decide on 38pt? ie how did you know teh graph would still be centered?

Comment: You're welcome. You had already centred the graph using your `[trim axis left, trim axis right]`. My `border={38pt 12pt}` then adds a 38pt border to the left and right equally, which keeps the graph centred, whichever numbers are used. I just came up with 38pt by trial and error.

Comment: Ah I see! So is the 38pt graph size dependent?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the size of the labels and ticks to the left of your axis. In other words, my solution is not particularly elegant.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally do you know how to get rid of those tick marks on the top axis and right hand axis?

Comment: Yes. Put `xtick pos=left` and `ytick pos=left` in your axis options. (The default is `both`.)