# How to make multiple pgfplots share legend and Y label, retaining same size and ability to reference each plot?

Tags: pgfplots

For some time now I have been trying to have two (or more) plots made with `pgfplot` side by side (figure below shows my goal for three), with the leftmost plot having the `ylabel`, the centre having the legend above it (or in case of an even number of plots having the legend centred between the two middle once).
Finally, I would like for each plot to have a referencable label and caption (besides the xlabel)

However, the plot with the `ylabel` and the one with the legend always gets smaller (due to the added graphics of the label and the legend, I know) and I have not been able to find a solution to the issue.
Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Below is the normal way I add three plots using `subfigure`:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
  X,Y,Z,N
  0,1,2,3
  1,2,3,4
  2,3,4,5
  4,4,5,6
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[ylabel=DATA TEXT, width=.95\textwidth]
        \addplot+ table[x=X, y=Y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\label{fig:y} Shows Y}
  \end{subfigure}~
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[width=.95\textwidth, legend style={at={(0.5,1.5)},anchor=north,legend columns=2}]
        \addplot+ table[x=X, y=Z, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \legend{DATA}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\label{fig:z} Shows Z}    
  \end{subfigure}~
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[width=.95\textwidth]
        \addplot+ table[x=X, y=N, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\label{fig:n} Shows N}    
  \end{subfigure}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Is there a way ...?" Of course there is, TeX is computationally complete (within limits). However, in order to find the solution best suited to your setting, and in order to be able to experiment with some code, *please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/110998).*

Comment: @gernot thank you for reminding me!

Comment: Does [Pgfplot figure off-center because of axis label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109598/pgfplot-figure-off-center-because-of-axis-label) solve the problem with the y label? A similar technique might also handle the legend.

Comment: I will try, the offcenter one

Comment: Doesn't work as the size of the plot it self is still affected